# Functions defined below are bounded or not?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have a set of functions ${{x}_{i}}:\mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}\to \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$ ($i=1,2,...,n$). Denote the independent variable with $t$. Suppose, there are ${{\eta }_{1}},{{\eta }_{2}},\ldots ,{{\eta }_{n}}\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{+}}$ coefficients such that the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{\eta }_{i}}{{x}_{i}}\left( t \right)}=c$ for all $t\ge 0$, where $c\in \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$. I would like to ask if the functions ${{x}_{i}}$ are bounded in this case. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are the $\eta_i$ strictly positive ?

Comment: Yes, combination coefficients are strictly positive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are bounded by $c/min\{\eta_{1}, \cdots, \eta_{n}\}$...?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_i(t)\ge 0$ and $\eta_i>0$, you have for any $1\le k\le n$
$$
0\le \eta_k x_k(t)\le \sum_{i=1}^n \eta_i x_i(t)=c\quad\Rightarrow\quad 0\le x_k(t)\le \frac{c}{\eta_k}.
$$
Thus, $x_k$ is bounded.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose there exists $\eta_i\neq 0$. Since every $\eta$ is non-negative, the function $t\mapsto x_i(t)$ is bounded according to your assumption.

If $\eta_i =0$, then there's nothing you can say.